ReorderableListView background overflows outside of container
I have a ReorderableListView inside a container with a fixed width and height. When the number of ListTile widgets exceeds the container's height, the background of the ReorderableListView overflows outside the container, but the foreground (text) of the ListTile widgets is clipped, as expected.
I have attached a gif as a visual aid, in which we can notice that the text and icon of each ListTile gets clipped, but not the background. We can also notice how the AppBar of my Scaffold widgget changes color when the list moves all the way up.

Here is my code:
Container(
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  child: ReorderableListView(
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      onReorder: (int oldIndex, int newIndex) { /* Some code here */ },
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < _selectedDataLabelSet.labels.length; index++)
          ListTile(
            selected: _selectedDataLabelIndex == index,
            selectedTileColor: colorScheme.primary,
            selectedColor: Colors.white,
            key: Key('$index'),
            tileColor: index.isOdd ? oddItemColor : evenItemColor,
            title: Text(_selectedDataLabelSet.labels[index]),
            onTap: () { /* Do something here */ },
          ),
      ]),
),

I tried:

Wrapping the ReorderableListView with a ConstrainedBox
Wrapping the ReorderableListView with a SingleChildScrollView
Adding the shrinkWrap: true and clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge to my ReorderableListView


This question is similar to: List Tiles out of container when scrolling. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As stated in top answer of mentioned issue, wrapping ListTile with Card works and I also tested wrapping it with Material and that works too! But I don't know the reason behind it to be honest and that's a question to me.
